# MaterializeCSS tall input

Tags: html, css, materialize

I have a MaterializeCSS input field which I want to be taller. I've tried setting a class "large" on the `<div class="input-field">` and on the `<input>` itself, but that doesn't seem to do anything. Setting the css `font-height` makes the text larger but the input field itself stays the same size.

Is there any way to make a large MaterializeCSS input field?

Thank you!

Comment: please add demo with https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-lahewf or code example

Comment: https://codepen.io/13cowado/pen/dyPVdNg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add those CSS lines to input, it will make the text higher and visible

```css
.validate{
    font-size: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'd like to make the icon on the left the same size, but when I give the icon a `font-height:100px` - see https://i.imgur.com/meprMny.png.